# Need clarification on svn update, How it is exactly works?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I did change one of my code in my php file. I committed those changes using SVN.
Then after discussion with my lead, i reverted those changes and made new changes in same file on local.
Then i took svn update.
I thought it will give previous changes in my local file, but it didn't.
I thought file get merged,but it didn't happened in same way.

How it exactly works let me know?

Comment: "i reverted those changes": please explain what you did exactly, which command you used.

Comment: I reverted those changes- is like i changed code from file i removed that particular code and changed with new one.

Comment: If you just wanted to know how svn update works you wouldn't be giving that context. It's clear that you seek help for a problem. We really need to know the exact menu items you used and the exact problem you face (your revert didn't show up in the repo, you lost local changes, whatever).